# Setting Mac OS X volume programmatically after 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audiotoolbox

Is there a way to set the Mac's System Volume using Objective-C? I tried using:

```
AudioDeviceSetProperty([[self class]defaultOutputDeviceID],
                       NULL, //time stamp not needed
                       0, //channel 0 is master channel
                       false,  //for an output device
                       kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
                       sizeof(Float32),
                       &volume);
```

But it is deprecated after [OS X 10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard); is there a better way to do this? Or will I have to settle for application volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Audio Hardware Services in AudioToolbox:

- [AudioToolbox Functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audiotoolbox_functions)
- [Audio Hardware Services Properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405208-audio_hardware_services_properti)

Here is some sample code assuming the same context as your other code:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume, 
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
};

AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData([self.class defaultOutputDeviceID], 
                                    &propertyAddress, 
                                    0, 
                                    NULL, 
                                    sizeof(Float32),
                                    &volume);
```

Comment: The link redirects to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox. Is that the intended?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've modified the link to the closest related thing I could find