# Using AudioToolbox from Swift to access OS X master volume

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, audiotoolbox

Is there a solution to setting the system's master volume from within my Swift app?

I read a lot about AudioToolbox and read some source examples in Objective-C. For example, I found this: *[Setting Mac OS X Volume Programatically after 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070819/setting-mac-osx-volume-programatically-using-xcode)*

But I can't get it working in Swift.

I am missing some example code in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioHardwareServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*(Code updated for Swift 4 and later, the Swift 2 and 3 versions can be found in the edit history.)*

This is what I got from translating the answers to *[Change OS X system volume programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715111/change-os-x-system-volume-programmatically)* and *[Setting Mac OS X volume programmatically after 10.6 (Snow Leopard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070819/setting-mac-osx-volume-programmatically-using-xcode)* to Swift (error checking omitted for brevity):

Required framework:

```
import AudioToolbox
```

Get default output device:

```
var defaultOutputDeviceID = AudioDeviceID(0)
var defaultOutputDeviceIDSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: defaultOutputDeviceID))

var getDefaultOutputDevicePropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
    mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))

let status1 = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
    AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject),
    &getDefaultOutputDevicePropertyAddress,
    0,
    nil,
    &defaultOutputDeviceIDSize,
    &defaultOutputDeviceID)
```

Set volume:

```
var volume = Float32(0.50) // 0.0 ... 1.0
var volumeSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: volume))

var volumePropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume,
    mScope: kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster)

let status2 = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(
    defaultOutputDeviceID,
    &volumePropertyAddress,
    0,
    nil,
    volumeSize,
    &volume)
```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, get the volume:

```
var volume = Float32(0.0)
var volumeSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: volume))

var volumePropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
    mSelector: kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume,
    mScope: kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster)

let status3 = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(
    defaultOutputDeviceID,
    &volumePropertyAddress,
    0,
    nil,
    &volumeSize,
    &volume)

print(volume)
```

Error checking has been omitted for brevity. Of course one should check the status return values for success or failure in a real application.

Credits go to *[Set OS X volume in OS X 10.11 using Swift without using the deprecated AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953948/set-os-x-volume-in-os-x-10-11-using-swift-without-using-the-deprecated-audiohard/36954944#36954944)* for using `AudioObjectSetPropertyData()`
instead of the deprecated `AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData()`.

As [noamtm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38557/noamtm) mentions in the comments, this works also for getting and setting the left-right balance, by passing

```
mSelector: kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterBalance
```

to `AudioObjectPropertyAddress()`.

Comment: cool. thanks a lot. Now i see my mistakes that i made with AudioDeviceId and the kAudio....

Comment: In Swift 5, you need to import `CoreAudio` as well, and the `kAudio` properties have the right type.

Comment: @zneak: Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the Code for Swift 4 (and 5). In my project, importing AudioToolbox was sufficient, even in Swift 5 (Xcode 10.2 beta).

Comment: Works perfectly Catalina 10.15.2, Swift 5, Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: Thanks, this is the first usable answer. Could you tell me how to get the default input device instead of output?

Comment: @duongel: Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for it. I want to add that left-right balance can also be controlled in the same way, just change `kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume` to `kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterBalance`. 
@MartinR please consider adding this note to the answer.