# Check if system volume is muted

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, audio

I'm Currently working on a small project, in which I need to check if the system volume is muted from the App Delegate.

As sound as the user `mute's/unmute's` the volume an function needs to be called.

I've found some things about [AudioToolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290751/how-to-set-systems-master-volume-from-a-swift-app-in-osx), but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

I know to look up if the default device is muted or not.  First, you need to look up the 'default' audio device hardware ID.  This can be done once and stored in your program.

```
    var propAddr = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: AudioObjectPropertySelector(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice),
        mScope: AudioObjectPropertyScope(kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal),
        mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))

    var defaultAudioHardwareID : AudioDeviceID = 0
    var propSize = UInt32(sizeof(uint32))

    let status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(AudioObjectID(kAudioObjectSystemObject), &propAddr, 0 , nil, &propSize, &defaultAudioHardwareID)
```

After that, you can look up if the device is muted.

```
    var propAddr = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
        mSelector: AudioObjectPropertySelector(kAudioDevicePropertyMute),
        mScope: AudioObjectPropertyScope(kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput),
        mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))

    var isMuted: uint32 = 0
    var propSize = UInt32(sizeof(uint32))

    let status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(defaultAudioHardwareID, &propAddr, 0, nil, &propSize, &isMuted)


    if isMuted != 0 {
        // Do stuff here
        return;
    }
```

I don't know if there's a way to get a notification when the mute state changes or not.

Comment: Super, it's what i need. Just need to find the event listener for the mute state change...

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'sizeof'`

Comment: @Egghead did you ever figure this out?