# macOS programmatically lower the volume of other apps

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm working on an assistant app similar to Siri, but instead of stopping music apps or whatever is playing the background, I'd like to lower the volume of the running app(s), speak, then increase it back to where it was.

What API(s) can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 9: How to change volume programmatically without showing system sound bar popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168497/ios-9-how-to-change-volume-programmatically-without-showing-system-sound-bar-po)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using AudioToolbox from Swift to access OS X master volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290751/using-audiotoolbox-from-swift-to-access-os-x-master-volume)

Comment: No, neither of these answer my question. The first is for iOS, the other is about adjusting the system overall volume.

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to do that?