# How should I update my code to avoid these "function is deprecated" warnings when compiling my CoreAudio program?

Tags: c, macos, deprecated, core-audio

I've got a MacOS/X program that uses CoreAudio to do sound output.  It works fine, but whenever I compile it, the compiler emits the "XXX is deprecated" warnings shown below.

My question is, how should I update/replace these function calls so that I get the same functionality but done in a non-deprecated way?  I can't seem to find any documentation on what Apple wants me to do in this case.

```
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myprogram.dir/MyProgram.cpp.o
/MyProgram.cpp:295:25: warning: 'AudioDeviceSetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   const OSStatus err = AudioDeviceSetProperty(cadi()->GetAudioDeviceID(), 0, 0, FALSE, kAudioDevicePropertyHogMode, sizeof(myPID), &myPID);
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:855:1: note: 'AudioDeviceSetProperty' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioDeviceSetProperty( AudioDeviceID                       inDevice,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:352:31: warning: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         const OSStatus err = AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener(deviceID, 0, false, kAudioDeviceProcessorOverload, PlaybackDevicePropertyChanged, NULL);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:884:1: note: 'AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener( AudioDeviceID                   inDevice,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:358:31: warning: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         const OSStatus err = AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener(deviceID, 0, false, kAudioDeviceProcessorOverload, PlaybackDevicePropertyChanged);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:911:1: note: 'AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener(  AudioDeviceID                   inDevice,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:437:24: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      OSStatus osErr = AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &outWritable);
                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:321:1: note: 'AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo(   AudioHardwarePropertyID inPropertyID,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:450:18: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         osErr = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &pluginAVT);
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:342:1: note: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioHardwareGetProperty(   AudioHardwarePropertyID inPropertyID,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:582:12: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   osErr = AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &outWritable);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:321:1: note: 'AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo(   AudioHardwarePropertyID inPropertyID,
^
/MyProgram.cpp:595:12: warning: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   osErr = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &pluginAVT);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/AudioHardwareDeprecated.h:342:1: note: 'AudioHardwareGetProperty' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
AudioHardwareGetProperty(   AudioHardwarePropertyID inPropertyID,
^
```

Comment: I guess you will have to research about each of these functions case by vase. Such as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070819/setting-mac-os-x-volume-programmatically-after-10-6-snow-leopard

Comment: @EugeneSh. the replacement function recommended in the answer to that question (`AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData()`) is also deprecated :/

Comment: You can use `AudioObjectSetPropertyData` for the `AudioDeviceSetProperty` calls.  Start with those then see what you have left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the definitions of the functions in `AudioHardwareDeprecated.h` you will find alternatives mentioned in the documentation.

Take `AudioDeviceSetProperty()` For example:

> Also note that the same functionality is provided by the function AudioObjectSetPropertyData().

This result in the following replacements:

**AudioDeviceSetProperty()**
Replace with `AudioObjectSetPropertyData()`

**AudioDeviceAddPropertyListener()**
Replace with `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener()` in conjunction with `AudioObjectPropertyListenerProc`

**AudioDeviceRemovePropertyListener()**
Replace with `AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener()` in conjunction with `AudioObjectPropertyListenerProc()`

**AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo()**
Replace with `AudioObjectHasProperty()`, `AudioObjectIsPropertySettable()` and `AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize()`

**AudioHardwareGetProperty()**
Replace with `AudioObjectGetPropertyData()`

Comment: Thanks Ruurd, that was helpful!   I think I have it sorted now :)